# Where can you get ebony arrows in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have seen people use these arrows on youtube but where can you get them from?

Comment: I *think* they'll start randomly dropping once you reach a certain level, but I'm not 100% on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [The Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Arrows_%28Skyrim%29)

> - Enemies that wield bows, such as guards and bandits, drop arrows
> - Arrows can be purchased from Blacksmiths in limited quantities. Arrow    strength is contingent upon Character Level. Arrows in larger
>     quantities can be purchased from Fletcher in Solitude or The Drunken Huntsmen in Whiterun.
> - With the implementation of the Dawnguard add-on, arrows can now be    crafted at a blacksmith's forge.
> - Arrows are notably farmed from guards doing target practice (though they only use steel arrows)

Also: [Ebony Arrows](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ebony_Arrow_%28Skyrim%29)

> - Starting around level 40 ebony arrows (along with all other ebony goods) become available in good quantity from blacksmith merchants
>     such as Eorlund Gray-Mane or at Warmaiden's.
>
>   - Enter the Labyrinthian and clear out Lost Valkygg. The Draugr Lord at the end next to the exit always carries an Ebony bow and a large
>       quantity of arrows, regardless of level.

Good Hunting!

Comment: to add onto this: once you've obtained a certain type of arrow, you can farm it by reverse pickpocketing that type of arrow onto the guards practicing archery in Solitude. They'll shoot unlimited numbers of those arrows at their targets, which you can then go and pick out at your leisure.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [the current answer:](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/91919/4797)

- Ebony Weapons appear in leveled lists (as loot or enemy item drop) starting at level 36 (enchanted
  varieties at level 37).
- Arrows can only be smithed if the [Dawnguard plug-in](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dawnguard) has been installed.
- With Dawnguard, it becomes possible to craft standard arrows using 1 piece of firewood plus an appropriate metal ingot.
- Ebony Arrows can be forged using the [Ebony Smithing](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ebony_Smithing#Ebony_Smithing) perk.
- Ebony Smithing requires 80 [Smithing](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing) skill.
- 3 Ebony Ores are obtained by mining Ebony Ore Veins. Cannot be purchased.
- 1 Ebony Ingot is obtained by smelting 2 Ebony Ores. Can be purchased at level >= 27.
- Ebony Ingots may be sold by [blacksmiths and general goods merchants](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Merchants) starting at level 27.
- Ebony Ore may be randomly found in Falmer loot starting at level 13.

[Places where you can mine Ebony ore veins or collect Ebony ore](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ebony#Mineral_Sources)

Source: UESP wiki, ["Ebony"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ebony) and ["Ammunition"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ammunition) article

Answer (score -1):

If you already have ebony arrows just pickpocket a archer take his arrows and put the ebony arrows in his inventory.  This way there will be multiple arrows coming out all you haft to do is just sit back and collect them.

Answer (score -1):

If you character has reached a sufficiently high level, Nordic Ruins become the best place to collect ebony arrows. If you are leveled high enough, most of the enemies in Nordic ruins will be Draugr Deathlords. These enemies use ebony weapons almost exclusively. Roughly 1/3 will be one handers with a sword or war axe and an ebony shield, roughly 1/3 will be two handers with any one of the two handed ebony weapons and roughly 1/3 will be archers with ebony bows(and corresponding arrows).

Comment: If someone downvotes my answer, could you please explain to me why? Maybe there is something I can do to make it better. I appreciate constructive criticism but don't appreciate downvotes for no reason. Thanks.